# Empirically estimating a project duration

Tags: language-agnostic, project-management, project-planning, estimation

What are common empirical formulas that can produce a rough estimate of project duration for waterfall methodology ( up to 20% fluctuation is acceptable). If it helps in narrowing down the answer,  you can assume that following is more or less known :

1. Number of devs is known and fixed, most devs are above average in terms of know-how, however some learning about domain-specific issues might be required.
2. Known and fixed max. number of app users.
3. Technology stack to be used is reasonably diverse (up to 4 different languages and up to 6 various platforms).
4. Interfacing to up to three  legacy systems is expected.

Please feel free to provide estimate methods which cover a broader scope than the above points, they are just provided for basic guidance.

Comment: Expect a minimum sigma of 1500%  from the oncoming answers :D

Comment: Rough estimates of this form are horribly unreliable.  Up to a 20% fluctuation is not possible.

Comment: http://rulesofthumb.org/rate.php?ruleid=3682

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming

Comment: @VadimKotov - right, because in programming you never need to do any estimations, right?

Comment: @Jas No need for sarcasm. I perfectly understand your point. This is old question, and now it is considered off-topic as defined in [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). We have [Project Management SE](https://pm.stackexchange.com/) or [Software Engineering SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) for such questions.

Comment: @VadimKotov - No sarcasm at all. A programmer could certainly never learn anything from the answers in this question. It is not like they ever need to do precise software estimations at the request of PM, or learn anything not related to strictly writing code which might have impact on their daily work. For example like in the book quoted in the top answer. Even more so since 7 years ago we had this *abundance* of a number of SE sites so shame on me for selecting specifically StackOverflow for posting this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do yourself a favor and pick up Steve McConnell's *[Software Estimation: Demystifying the Black Art](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735605351)*. If you have access to past estimates and actuals this can greatly aid in producing a useful estimate. Otherwise I recommend this book and identifying a strategy from it most applicable to your situation.

Comment: Cool, I'll make sure to pick it up, thanks for recommending it.

Comment: @Jas Another suggestion switch from a waterfall methodology to spiral. The bakes in the assumption that initial requirements are incomplete and/or incorrect.

Comment: spiral methodology - is that an agile type methodology? Haven't heard that term before...

Comment: @Jas - basically iterative waterfall - wikipedia link for you: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiral_model

Answer (score 3):

Only expect to utilize 70% of your developers time. The other 30% will be spent in meetings, answering email, taking the elevator, etc. For example if they work 8hrs a day, they will only be able to code for 5.6 to 6.5 hours a day. Reduce this number if they work in a noisy environment where people are using the telephone.

Add 20% to any estimate a developer gives the project manager.

Lines of code is useless as a metric in estimating a project.

Success or failure depends on concise requirements from the customer. If the requirements aren't complete, count on the customer being not happy with the finished product.

Count on the fact that not all of the requirements will be dictated by the customer. There will be revisions to the requirements throughout the project.

Comment: The developer's time could be even lower than 70% depending on the interruptions. They may be required to do some 3rd level support, and when the interruptions come impact their effectiveness. I've been in the situation of having twice daily 1/2 hour status meetings (10am and 2:30pm) and had the productivity of the team go totally to pot.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1.  Create a schedule that is as granulated as is reasonably possible.
Step 2.  Ask the people involved how long their features will take.
Step 3.  Create an Excel spreadsheet which maps predictions to actual times.
Step 4.  Repeat steps 1-3 for all new projects.  Make use of an aggregated mapping from previous instances of step 3 to translate developer estimates to actual estimates.

Note that there are tools which can do this for you.

> See also
>   [Evidence-based-scheduling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/evidence-based-scheduling).

Comment: This is essentially how Scrum does it except you repeat steps 1-3 every sprint (couple of weeks in my team, a month is also common). Keep doing this and your estimates will improve. But.. and this is the most important.. make sure you do number 2. Otherwise it is a deadline, not an estimate and software projects tend to never meet deadlines.

Answer (score 1):

This project is not going to be cheap...

> Number of devs is known and fixed,
>   most devs are above average in terms
>   of know-how, however some learning
>   about domain-specific issues might be
>   required.

This is a good thing. You don't want to flood the number of developers into the project. Though if you go above around 10 people, do count every 2 as only 1, as the rest will go up in overhead. Unless you can split the task into something that can be handled by two totally separate teams. Then you could have a chance of getting some traction.

> Known and fixed max. number of app
>   users.

This means that you can with more certainty land your architecture early on, as you can estimate how much effort you must put into scaling your solution. This is a good thing. Make sure that you work within these limits and never ever fool yourself into thinking "it's fast enough". It almost never is if you doubt that it could be too slow...

> Technology stack to be used is
>   reasonably diverse (up to 4 different
>   languages and up to 6 various
>   platforms).

This isn't as important as to do your people know this stack/set of languages? If there are any learning involved, raise the estimate x2 or x3 if you don't perform a proof of concept up front to learn the technology. Or even better, take the pain and get some coursing. If the language for implementation or technology to be used is unknown, then it is quite likely that you will misuse the technology and do things that will screw stuff up.

Make sure that the technology is proven or you'll end up getting bitten by it.

- Are the source available for the tools/technology?
- Do you get support?
- Do you understand the product and or used it before?
- Have the customer used it before?

If too many of these questions get a no, add some (or a lot of) additional time to the sum.

> Interfacing to up to three legacy
>   systems is expected.

This is really a kicker. For legacy integration ask yourself:

- Has anyone else integrated with them?
- Do you have access to people with knowledge of these systems?
- Do they intend to share this knowledge with you?
- Do you have to wait for changes being created in these systems?
- Are there test systems available for you to use?
- Are there development systems available for you to use?

Again, if too many of these questions has a "no" on them, then be afraid. You should also know that actual integration takes about 3-5 times longer than you actually think.

This isn't a project that I would have given a table grabbing estimate for. Do yourself and your customer a favor and do this by the hour. If not, you will as times go by start cutting corners to cover up your lack of progress/underestimation... And both you and your customer will suffer.

Comment: @Jas - Thanks :-) Hope it can help in your estimation process - I've been through some integration projects before and they are always a pain.

Comment: The words "interfacing legacy" are generally depicting a future drag down. From the people maintaining those systems, or for the lack of them.

Comment: @Belarius I've encountered those as well, though the thing with computer systems is that they will be replaced or die. That's how the world is and people need to understand that this is how our trade is. The thing is that you must either be part of the new wave or find something else. As an owner of an old system you are so very in position to be a master in a new one....

Comment: And one more thing - not all legacy systems are to be replaced. They might fit their task excellent and do a great job. Though they might not be suited for building the applications that are needed today (web/mobile), and it could be hard to expand them. As a customer you then must choose to either rewrite in a new platform or integrate.

Answer (score 0):

There are many cost estimation software tools that can greatly ease the pain of cost estimation, we use ProjectCodeMeter. I know these tools are not perfect, but they do save time getting started by pointing towards the right direction.

[Try this list of estimation tools on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_development_estimation_software).